# Does attaching a booking confirmation for a future trip as well improve the chances of obtaining a multiple-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, tourist-visas

When applying for a Schengen visa, one needs to provide a booking confirmation for their trip to the Schengen area. Does attaching a second booking confirmation of a trip 3 or 6 months down the line improve the prospects of obtaining a multiple-entry Schengen visa when applying?

Or, instead, could this hurt the chances of obtaining a multiple-entry visa since a second trip could imply higher costs associated with the travel in general?

In case it is relevant, I am talking about 2 trips to the same country for tourism purposes.

Comment: It is difficult to know, and to answer. It depends on your residence and nationality (and how frequent is illegal immigration from your home country). For me booking confirmation gives me that you have some plans, not much more (you may be able to get refund, or just accounted as expenses to enter in a country)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally, visas are issued using a progressive scale:

- First, single-entry short validity visas, basically strictly limited to the dates of the itinerary (+15 days grace period in theory, *ahahah*).

  If the itinerary requires it, a dual or multiple entry visa may be issued, but still with a short validity.

  If for some reason you need to make two trips very close one to the other, they may issue a dual or multiple entry visa covering both, but I doubt this would happen for a second trip 3 to 6 months later.
- After several successful visits (normally 3 visits within the last 2 years), a multiple-entry visas for a year is issued on the next application, then two years, then five years.
- However there is a lot of leeway in the Schengen Visa Code, and consulates/embassies can deliver longer or shorter visas based on nearly any reason they can think of.
- It usually ends up on the shorter side: many people have met the above requirements and are still issued short validity single entry visas on subsequent applications.
- However:

> a multiple-entry visa valid for up to five years may be issued to applicants who prove the need or justify their intention to travel frequently or regularly, provided that they prove their integrity and reliability, in particular the lawful use of previous visas, their economic situation in the country of origin and their genuine intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa for which they have applied.

Basically that means that if you are going to have to travel very regularly (think: for business reasons, multiple times a year) **and** have a very very strong case (think: you have a stable job which pays well above minimum wage in the destination country) **and** have a history of successful visa use in Schengen or comparable places (UK, US, Canada, Australia...) then they might issue a multiple-entry long-validity visa right away.

But again, they may not.

Note that how strict or lax they are depends both on the Schengen country you are applying for a visa from, and the country you reside/are from.

We don't know your circumstances, so it's difficult to judge, but for visits for tourism purposes, with vague plans, a long delay between the trips, for a first visa, I would think it's not particularly useful, and on the contrary, may make things more confusing, more difficult to evaluate, and would of course require more documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by "vague plans"? I mean, apart from a booking confirmation, what could make the future trip less vague?

Comment: @hb20007 maybe a specific reason one has to come back, a specific event, a full itinerary, a reason to justify why you need to make two separate trips rather than a single longer one… in any case you would have to provide all the documentation for the second trip as for the first one.

Answer (score 1):

My partner wanted a multiple entry visa so I wrote a short cover letter for him to send in saying he would like to be considered for a multiple entry visa as he would like to visit the Netherlands with me in June (first trip was in January in France).
He was granted a one year multiple entry visa a couple days later.

Comment: Were you a resident of a Schengen member state?

Comment: I’m a resident of New Zealand. He is a Saudi resident.

Comment: Okay, in this case I believe that there is no difference whether you wrote the cover letter or he wrote it himself.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I only wrote it as him. Which is why I knew it was included in his pack he sent in. There was no firm travel plans and the only place the multiple entry visa was mentioned was in the cover letter and where it was ticked in the application form. So he was approved without travel plans further than “I’d like to..”

Comment: It's an interesting case, but I suppose that everyone would "like to" have the permission to travel again. So, I am inclined to believe that the cover letter had a minimal impact on the outcome.