# Does acquiring a multiple-entry Schengen visa guarantee that a future visa will also be multiple-entry for a stable traveler?

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, tourist-visas

As indicated in various answers on this site ([example](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/186008/46228)), a multiple-entry Schengen visa is usually issued (if requested) to travelers after several successful visits (e.g., 3 visits within the last 2 years).

A traveler applies again for a multiple-entry visa after having already obtained one after several successful visits, and also used the multiple-entry visa. Also assuming that the traveler’s situation is stable (not a lot of time has passed, same income, submits similar documents, etc.), is it a guarantee that (s)he will be issued a multiple-entry visa again? If so, does it depend on whether the traveler is applying to the same or different country as previous times?

Comment: Certainly a good travel history is in the applicant's favor, but nothing is _ever_ guaranteed. More likely, perhaps, but guaranteed...no. Remember that if "not a lot of time has passed," the visa examiner may wonder if the traveler is trying to live in the country by making multiple and repeated trips. This thought (in the examiner's mind) will not be helpful to the applicant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by David in the comments, it is not guaranteed. For example, depending on the situation, the visa examiner may suspect that the traveler is trying to live in the country by making multiple repeated trips.

Answer (score 3):

As others have answered, nothing is ever **guaranteed**.

The Schengen Visa Code has **standard** rules with the standard progression of 3 short-validity visas followed by 1-year, then 2-year, then 5-year multiple entry visas, and from then on, they are **supposed** to continue renewing with 5-year visas (if you keep the interval between visas short enough, and of course if your meet the conditions of the visas, and your circumstances haven't changed, or changed favourably).

But the Code also has lots of provisions allowing the consulate/embassy to **give you shorter (or longer!) visas based on nearly any reason they want**. Some countries just have a bad history with citizens from some country or another and apply much stricter rules to them, and that's it, for instance. Or their rules may change over time.

It is more likely that this happens if you change the country you request the visa from. I think we had a question recently on this topic, where the OP had requested a new visa from Germany which resulted in a short-validity visa and not the expected longer one, but I don't remember the details.

Of course this does not mean you should resort to visa-shopping by manipulating what you tell them about your travel plans, but if you can make sure your (first) travel plans continue with the same country that's probably the better option.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no guarantee.**

Getting a multiple entry visa once, and using it reasonably, increases the probability of getting it again. But your circumstances might change, or policies might change.

Comment: I am assuming that the circumstances have not changed: "Also assuming that the traveler’s situation is stable (not a lot of time has passed, same income, submits similar documents, etc.)"

Comment: @hb20007, the same income may be worth less due to inflation. Or purchasing power parity is the same, but exchange rates changed. *No guarantee.*